# Get and display data of logged in user in a c# application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I've made a Login/Sign Up application with C# using WPF and XAML. When a user logs in I'd like to display some of the info that they input into the Sign Up form but no matter what user logs in, it always displays the info of the last registered account. How can I get it to display data based on the currently logged in user? 
This is the code that I've been able to muster up so far.

**This is the page where I want user information to be displayed**(as textblocks)

```
public partial class User_Homepage : Page
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=HP;Initial Catalog=User_SignUpDB;Integrated Security=True;";

        public User_Homepage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlCon.Open();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM tblSignUP";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            createCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                nameTxt.Text = (dr["StudentName"].ToString());

            }

            sqlCon.Close();   
        }
    }
```

**This is the code from User Login Page**

```
private void UserSignInBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HP;Initial Catalog=User_SignUpDB;Integrated Security=True;");

            try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT COUNT (1) FROM tblSignUP WHERE StudentName=@StudentName AND Password=@Password";
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", tbID.Text);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PB.Password);
                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    if (count == 1)
                    {

                        // Custom Message Box and Dim Effect
                        var jim = new Dim();

                        jim.Show();
                        this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                        var lsmb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.LoginSuccessfulMsgBox();
                        lsmb.ShowDialog();

                        this.Effect = null;
                        jim.Close();

                        //Move to User Homepage
                        var User_Homepage = new User_Homepage();
                        NavigationService.Navigate(User_Homepage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // Custom Message Box and Dim Effect 2
                        var him = new Dim();

                        him.Show();
                        this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                        var rmdlgb = new ReturnMessageDialogueBox();
                        rmdlgb.ShowDialog();

                        this.Effect = null;
                        him.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

**This is the code from User Registration/Create New Account Page**

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserAdd", sqlCon);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                 
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", tbStudentName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolName", tbSchoolName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseName", tbHouseName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prog", tbProg.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", tbPhoneNumber.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", tbAddress.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pbPassword.Password.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    var dim = new Dim();
                    dim.Show();
                    this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                    var cmb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.RegistrationComplete();
                    cmb.ShowDialog();

                    this.Effect = null;
                    dim.Close();
                    Clear();
                }
```

**And heres the SQL stored procedure that I used**

```
USE [User_SignUpDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UserAdd]    Script Date: 5/2/2019 5:46:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[UserAdd]
@StudentName varchar(50),
@SchoolName varchar(50),
@HouseName varchar(50),
@Prog varchar(50),
@PhoneNumber varchar(50),
@Address varchar(250),
@Password varchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO tblSignUp(StudentName,SchoolName,HouseName,Prog,PhoneNumber,Address,Password)
    VALUES (@StudentName,@SchoolName,@HouseName,@Prog,@PhoneNumber,@Address,@Password)
```

So ultimately, what I want to do is display StudentName, HouseName, and Prog in their respective textboxes, based on who is logged in.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Your query `"SELECT * FROM tblSignUP";` is lacking a `WHERE Id = @CurrentUserId` clause, assuming your primary key is the `Id` column. Try storing  the PK of the user after logging in instead of reading the count.

Comment: There is a primary key "userID", but it was never used. I've tried using ```WHERE userID = @StudentName``` but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the database design has a lot of flaws.
Firstly, you need an unique identifier to identify each individual.

As i understood, you're using the "StudentName" for logging in, which is a bad practice. What if you have duplicate names? Therefore you need another unique column labeled as "username" which you could refer when logging in.

So when you have changed your table structure, change the query too.

change ---> `string query = "SELECT COUNT (1) FROM tblSignUP WHERE StudentName=@StudentName AND Password=@Password";`
 to    ---> `string query = "SELECT COUNT (1) FROM tblSignUP WHERE username=@Username AND Password=@Password";`

In addition to that, in your home page, you have to be specific on what information to be queried from the DB. 
Currently it's ---> `string query = "SELECT * FROM tblSignUP";`
And it should be changed to --> `string query = "SELECT * FROM tblSignUP WHERE username = @Username";`

Comment: It throws an exception telling me that the stored procedure expects a @username  now

Comment: And should the @username be a unique identifier or varchar?

Comment: Usernames are mostly Alphanumeric characters. I.E RavianXReaver123, JojoAmankwa42.

Comment: OK, I was able to fix the exception problem by commenting out ```sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();``` and now what happens is that, when I click the sign in button nothing happens, it doesn't load the next page. Is there a problem?

Comment: You should make use of debugging; setting up break points, writing to CommandLine. That allows you to check whether you get expected results. This method doesn't require you to have any additional logic, stick to your default. You just have to check whether the username matches any of ur db fields and return 1 or 0 as u have done above. if value is 1, then query again and retrieve the information belonging to that username.

Comment: Are there any other methods of doing this? i.e. displaying the info of a given user, possibly on that doesn't use the database

Comment: What does the "$" at the beginning of the query do?

Comment: Directly or indirectly, we all get information about a particular object from databases. May i know with which part you're having the problem now? and sorry about the $ sign, i was trying to use "String interpolation" and then saw you were using parameters.

Comment: In the user homepage, whenever I use ```"SELECT * FROM tblSignUP WHERE StudentName=@StudentName";``` I have to use ```createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName",nameTxt.Text);``` or else the next page doesnt load. Now when I use the addwithvalue the page loads alright, but the info displayed is always that of the 11th saved row in my table no matter what user I login with.
If I cant find the solution, I wanted to know if theres any other (direct) approach since im still just a beginner;
I wanna use the proper method, like how they'd do it in a company or somin'?

Comment: Idk if maybe I should change something in the database or maybe change the server entirely

Comment: Do you happen to have any duplicate entries of the same Student name?

Comment: Yes, about 4, could that be the problem?

Comment: ofcourse that's the problem ^_^ that's why i told you to depend on username(which is supposed to be unique) and not their name

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. I've decided to try and learn a little bit more about SQL, database and user logins, then build a new table for the app

Comment: Cheers mate! always go from the bottom =) then you'll understand better

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a user log in you have the the tbID.Text, you can save this variable, and in the home page re use it like this `"SELECT * FROM tblSignUP WHERE studentName LIKE tbID.Text"` (ofc you cant do it exactly like this, you have to make the proper sql statement but thats the way you do it) you can basically use the same principle that you use in the user log in page. This will get you the user you have just logged in

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is an exact duplicate of your previous post - which was closed. That is a big red flag to you - you need to understand why that happened. SO is pretty accommodating and a closed question means the community thinks you can do better.

So let's start. First, don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Just don't. To go along with that, don't be a lazy developer - something encouraged by methods/functions like addwithvalue.

Next, you have this:

```
        SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
        createCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

Why? You create a new SqlCommand object. Why do you need to clear the parameters? Start thinking about your code and stop blindly writing statements if you don't understand what they do. If you find code that you reuse, LEARN what it does, adapt it to your own goals.

Next, we see that you are getting the same questions that you did not really respond to with the prior thread. Your application needs to "remember" the details of user that logs in. And note that how a user logs in will differ between an existing user and a new user. You have 2 different code paths here but they ultimately need to do the same thing - grant access to the user and establish information in your app that allows it to function for that logged in user.

*As an aside, no one reading your question knows your skill level, your goals, your development environment, or your work situation. A student learning a first language needs a different level of guidance then one with significant experience. A member of a development team needs another level (and should be asking team members first before posting). If you don't provide any clues (or tell us explicitly), the suggestions and comments may not make much sense. They might also seem condescending. Posting questions in public forum is not as easy as one might think. Learn to [ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) that encourage others to help.*

So what "information" does your app require after a successful login? You tell us. I will guess that it needs some (perhaps all) of the information involved in the registration logic. You might also need the primary key for that row in the table. What is the primary key and how do you get it? You tell us. I'm guessing that the actual primary key value(s) of the user will be needed in other parts of your application. Based on the login code, username seems to be the natural key (which I hope is enforced with the proper constraint) but the actual primary key might be a different column(s).

Now you might think that you can simply save the username some place after a successful login and simply retrieve it everywhere you need it. You can - but that is a very inefficient approach to application design. Why? Think about it. You can try this approach but that does not change the need to remember a minimal set of login information.

So let's loop back to the prior comment about 2 code paths. Your "existing user" logic simply verifies that the username/password exist in a row in your table. I'll ignore the problems with storing passwords as plain text - you should not. And you should carefully consider what information is needed for a successful login based on the natural key of the table. Names are often not unique within a school, much less between schools. Again - as a learning experience this particular detail is not too important. As code to be implemented in a production system, it is very important.

When a user completes the new account logic, your app has all (or at least the vast majority of) the information associated with the user. Your login logic should do the same thing. Determine what information about the user your app needs, find a way to "remember" this information within your app, and then add the code to those paths to retrieve/save it. You may need to consider the opposite logic as well - provide a way to clear that information and return your app to the same state it was when first started.

Comment: I'm basically a beginner when it comes to C# and SQL, I've only been doing it for 4 months. What I want to display is the StudentName, HouseName, and Prog. I have a primary key in the database called UserID but I never really used it for anything (I cant even find an @UserID), You said I should find a way to remember the information within the app, not the database?
And whats this about addwithvalue and storing passwords as plain text? thats what I learned from a tutorial.

Comment: And about the duplicate, I had already added the necessary code and rewrites but no one would answer and I was still on hold, they later closed my question, and wouldn't even get back to it, that's some seriously poor moderating. I knew reposting the exact same thing wouldn't be the best idea but how I was treated in the previous post was simply rude!, shame on you StackOverflow.